# weights are not working correctly in linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a beginner in android development.I'm trying to make a layout,which support both landscape and portrait images.
For,example if the image is portrait then there should be white spaces around it and if the image is landscape then it would take the whole width of the imageview and both of them should maintain the aspect ratio.I'm using json to get images from the URL and using array adapter to inflate the layout in listview.
When the layout is inflated one the linear layout's weight changes automatically
and I have no idea why it's doing like that? What should be the approach to do  that should, I scale the image using java or is there any other way around?

Here are the screenshots of the layout
[First row of the listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG4d9.png)
[Second row pf the listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnuSP.png)

**Note**:You can see that in the second screenshot, the height of the first linear layout is bigger than the linear layout in the first screenshot(*where user's profile picture is shown*)

timelinerowlayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ccc"
android:padding="10dp">

<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.35"
            android:background="@drawable/border">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="10dp">


                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/userProfilePicture"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ppplaceholder"
                    app:riv_border_color="#333333"
                    app:riv_border_width="2dip"
                    app:riv_corner_radius="5dip"
                    app:riv_mutate_background="true"
                    app:riv_oval="true"
                    app:riv_tile_mode="repeat" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/username"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/userProfilePicture"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userProfilePicture"
                    android:text="Small Text"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/userpostimage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/bc" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.16">



        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.gitesh.timeline.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.gitesh.timeline;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.TextHttpResponseHandler;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import Classes.PostAdapter;
import Classes.posts;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    ListView datalist;
    PostAdapter PostAdapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    datalist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    datalist.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (datalist.getChildAt(0) != null) {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(datalist.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && datalist.getChildAt(0).getTop() == 0);
            }
        }
    });
    swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    Typeface cFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "SAMARN__.TTF");
    Typeface fontAwesome = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
    PostAdapter = new PostAdapter(this, R.layout.timelinerowlayout, cFont);
    datalist.setAdapter(PostAdapter);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    /**
     * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
     * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
     */
    swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                                    bindData();
                                }
                            }
    );


}

/**
 * This method is called when swipe refresh is pulled down
 */
@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    bindData();
}


public void bindData() {


    try {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(true, 80, 443);
        client.get("http://indianroute.roms4all.com/fetch_post.php", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res) {
                        decodeJson(res);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res, Throwable t) {
                        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + res, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}

private void decodeJson(String result) {
    try {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(result);
        String username, story, picture, check_in, userprofilePicture;
        for (int count = 0; count < jArr.length(); count++) {
            JSONObject obj = jArr.getJSONObject(count);
            username = obj.getString("username");
            story = obj.getString("story");
            picture = obj.getString("picture");
            check_in = obj.getString("check_in");
            userprofilePicture = obj.getString("userprofilePicture");
            posts posts = new posts(username, story, picture, check_in, userprofilePicture);
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            PostAdapter.add(posts);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


}
```

PostAdapter.java

```
package Classes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.gitesh.timeline.R;
import com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Gitesh on 14-06-2016.
 */
public class PostAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

List list = new ArrayList();
Typeface samarn;

public PostAdapter(Context context, int resource, Typeface cFont) {
    super(context, resource);
    samarn = cFont;
}

@Override
public void add(Object object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row = convertView;
    PostHolder postHolder;


    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.timelinerowlayout, parent, false);
        postHolder = new PostHolder();
        postHolder.username = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.username);
        postHolder.userPostImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.userpostimage);
        postHolder.userprofilePicture = (RoundedImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.userProfilePicture);
        row.setTag(postHolder);
    } else {
        postHolder = (PostHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    posts posts = (posts) this.getItem(position);
    postHolder.username.setTypeface(samarn);
    postHolder.username.setText(posts.getUsername());
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(posts.getUserProfilePicture()).placeholder(R.drawable.ppplaceholder).priority(Picasso.Priority.HIGH).into(postHolder.userprofilePicture);
    Picasso.with(getContext()).load(posts.getPictue()).placeholder(R.drawable.postplaceholder).into(postHolder.userPostImage);
    return row;
}

static class PostHolder {
    TextView username;
    ImageView userPostImage;
    com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView userprofilePicture;

}


}
```

Comment: did you try using centerInside scale method instead of fitCenter?

Comment: yeah i did but still getting the same result

Comment: @jankigadhiya i saw your answer bu you deleted it :/

Comment: I deleted it because it didn't help you..!! @GiteshKhurani

Answer (score 0):

If you are using horizontal linear layout(`android:orientation="horizontal"`) then make width as `0dp`and if it is vertical linear layout give height as `0dp`
.Then give weights to child views.

Comment: but i'm not using orientation="horizontal" anywhere

Comment: if you are not giving any orientation,it will take orientation="horizontal" as default.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `weight_sum = 3` and the inner views of that layout have weight `0.35`, `1.5` and `1.16` accordingly.

```
0.35 + 1.5 + 1.16 = 3.01
```

So the sum of the weight you have defined to your inner views **does not exactly equal to 3**

Comment: changed to 3.01,still nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your layout with this, i've changed layout weights

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ccc"
android:padding="10dp">

<!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@drawable/border">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/userProfilePicture"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ppplaceholder"
                app:riv_border_color="#333333"
                app:riv_border_width="2dip"
                app:riv_corner_radius="5dip"
                app:riv_mutate_background="true"
                app:riv_oval="true"
                app:riv_tile_mode="repeat" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/username"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/userProfilePicture"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userProfilePicture"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.3">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/userpostimage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/bc" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where did you used the weight sum in the layout?

Comment: yup,but you missed some closing tags i guess and i tired you layout its not working

Comment: I added missing closing tags in the update, sorry but i don't have editor here